# matlab sum vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

Hi I have an object A which contains 9 vectors all of size [1 3], three dimensional vectors. How do I sum all of these to create a new vector of size [1 3] i.e. how to I take the contribution of each vector, and sum each of their contributions to give me a final vector. Thanks in advance. My vectors are stored in a cell array. How A is defined:

```
 ri = Rix{1,1};
 rj = Riy{1,1};


 vec2 = @(i)[ri(i), rj(i), 0];
 A = arrayfun(vec2, reshape(1:numel(ri), size(ri)), 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

and this is what I have tried so far:

```
 B = cellfun(@(A)nansum(A(:))'un', 0);
```

with this error

??? b = cellfun(@(distance)nansum(distance(:))'un', 0);
                                               |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Comment: Show us the definition of A and [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `cellfun` is not the way to go here, because your resultis only one vector element, not several vectors. Like @Vidar suggested, `cell2mat` is a good way to solve this problem. Regardless to your question, however: you have a syntax error with `cellfun`. Read [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) if you want to use it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dummy = [1 2 3];
A = {dummy;dummy;dummy;dummy;dummy;dummy;dummy;dummy;dummy}
Asum = sum(cell2mat(A));
```

Result:

```
Asum = [9 18 27]
```

As you can see, `cell2mat` is the trick here.

Comment: HI Vidar - this works. I made a minor edit for my case as I has a two dimensional cell array, rather than just a one dimensional array. My edit was Asum = sum(cell2mat(A(:))); Thanks very much for your help

Comment: +1: I suggest to do `Asum = sum(cell2mat({A{:}}'))` though, so that it can also handle cases where cell-array `A` has two dimensions or more.